# Java OpenCV VideoCapture properties not being considered. Need to avoid “while true” for latest frame. Multi-camera environment

Tags: java, multithreading, opencv

I am trying to create a multi-camera software that uses OpenCV for RTSP video stream processing (both displaying and processing of specific frames for ALPR). The issue I am having for the longest time is having to use a threaded while true for each camera whose only job is to “grab()” frames and then retrieve and process them in another thread so that I always get the latest frame.

```
Runnable streamGrabTask = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                stream.grab();
            }
        }
    };
```

This gets very resource consuming very fast with multiple cameras. I have tried using the VideoIo properties, but they have no effect whatsoever.

```
VideoCapture.set(Videoio.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, anyInt);
VideoCapture.get(Videoio.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES); //returns 0 no matter what

VideoCapture.set(Videoio.CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE, anyInt);
VideoCapture.get(Videoio.CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE); // returns 0.0 no matter what
```

The display and process task ideally looks like this and there is no need for another thread to grab:

```
Runnable displayTask = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                stream.grab();
                stream.retrieve(concurrentMatMap.get(imageView.getId()));
         //stuff hapenning here
        }
    };

    ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(displayTask, 500, 200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

But like this, the display lags behind and takes the frames from an internal buffer, I assume, to which I have no control.

I am using opencv_java451, JavaFX11 and Java 15. Is there a way to grab the latest frame without the need to have a while true thread for each camera? Or is there something I can do to have the properties considered so that the buffer size, or Pos_frames is considered? If not, are there alternatives to OpenCV that are actually up to date? Xuggler is halted and VLCJ is paid, resource consuming and not reliable multi-threaded.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I maintain a fork of Xuggler since several years. You can take a look at https://github.com/olivierayache/xuggle-xuggler

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will check it out. Will there be a new release or do I have to compile the library? I have 0 experience with such things..

Comment: You can find the last snapshots here https://dl.cloudsmith.io/public/olivier-ayache/first-repo/maven/xuggle/xuggle-xuggler-server-all-debug/5.7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

Comment: This build is for Linux and Windows what platform do you work with ?

Comment: I am working with Windows. Also, do you think the latest version of Xuggler would help get the latest frame without "while true"? I already tested with 5.4 and it's lagging behind. And I meant the link is not working.

Comment: This link explains how to use the dependency https://cloudsmith.io/~olivier-ayache/repos/first-repo/packages/detail/maven/xuggle-xuggler-server-all-debug/5.7.0-20210208.180732-1/a=noarch;xg=xuggle/#install

Comment: Thanks! I managed to get it running but with the same issue: unless I do a while true, I keep getting frames for a buffer, not the latest and after some time it fails. I need the readPacket() to happen every 200 milliseconds and to return the latest frame, which is not happening.